# python file write is not creating a new file

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have a django app, I received binary audio data from a javascript client, and I'm trying to send it to the google cloud speech to text API. The problem is that, python is not writing the binary audio data to a file. So I'm getting

```
with io.open(file_name, "rb") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.........\\gcp_cloud\\blog\\audio_file.wav'
```

I replaced the first part of the path with ...........

Here is the client side code

```
        rec.ondataavailable = e => {
          audioChunks.push(e.data);
          if (rec.state == "inactive"){
            let blob = new Blob(audioChunks,{type:'audio/wav; codecs=MS_PCM'});
            recordedAudio.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            recordedAudio.controls=true;
            recordedAudio.autoplay=true;
            sendData(blob)
          }
        }
```

and here is my sendData function

```
function sendData(data) {
    let csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
    let response=fetch("/voice_request", {
    method: "post",
    body: data,
    headers: { "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken },
    })

    console.log('got a response from the server')
    console.log(response)
}
```

and here is the DJango view that handles the binary audio data from the client

```
def voice_request(request):
    #print(request.body)
    fw = open('audio_file.wav', 'wb')
    fw.write(request.body)
    file_name = os.path.join(current_folder, 'audio_file.wav')
    #file_name = os.path.join(current_folder, 'Recording.m4a')
    client = speech.SpeechClient()

    # The language of the supplied audio
    language_code = "en-US"

    # Sample rate in Hertz of the audio data sent
    sample_rate_hertz = 16000

    encoding = enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16
    config = {
        "language_code": language_code,
        #"sample_rate_hertz": sample_rate_hertz,
        #"encoding": 'm4a',
    }
    with io.open(file_name, "rb") as f:
        content = f.read()

    audio = {"content": content}

    fw.close()

    response = client.recognize(config, audio)

    print('response')
    print(response)
    for result in response.results:
        # First alternative is the most probable result
        alternative = result.alternatives[0]
        print(u"Transcript: {}".format(alternative.transcript))

    return HttpResponse(response)
```

Comment: Why aren’t you using a context manager for `’audio_file.wav’`? Also, where in your code do you create the file? I’m not sure I understand what the issue is, as far as I can tell you’re trying to read a file that doesn’t exist, which obviously leads to an error.

Comment: once you save the file audio_file.wav in the voice_request view, do you get a valid wav file saved. Also when saving with fw.write(request.body), you are writing to the current folder. So why not read it directly from the current folder  without specifying the complete path with os.path.join(current_folder....

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I don't know what a context manager is, but I'll look it up. I am writing to a file, `fw.write(request.body)`, I thought this would create a file if it doesn't exist, and overwrite an existing one. Since it's not working, how would I achieve this affect?

Comment: @bhaskarc I can't see a file in my working directory. I guess it's not really writing to a file. I changed it to specify the file directly, and now I'm not getting a file not found error, but the google cloud API isn't returning any responses. And I still can't see the file in my directory.

Comment: @Rockstar5645 As far as I am aware, the `open(..., ‘wb’)` _should_ create the file if it doesn’t exist. A context manager is created with a `with` statement, you’re already using one elsewhere in your code! Change it so that it uses a context manager, and see if that fixes things?

Comment: What does print (request.body) and print(type(request.body)) show ?

Answer (score 0):

you should use `with io.open(file_name, "wb") as f:` or `with io.open(file_name, "ab") as f:`
because `r` mean read-only, `w` mean "rewrite"

you can refer: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open